# Do we need "put your internet services here" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

This pop-up in the chat when I was asked why I was removing the [last.fm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/last.fm). Remember that Last.FM is a Web Service. Ubuntu has a client but up until now nobody has asked a question before about this, but then we have other tags about other web services like YouTube.

Now the reasoning to remove this tags is simple, if there's a problem with any of those services is unlikely that the problem is the service but something local. You can't run a web service in your system of the size of YouTube (if you can, you should be answering questions instead), so who is the most likely culprit that you can't use these services?

1. Browser (Chrome/ium, Firefox, etc.)
2. Plugin (Flash, Java, Shockwave (?), Silverlight)
3. Network connection
4. PEBCAK.
5. Anything but Youtube
6. ...
7. ...
8. ...
9. If it's the Webservice then nothing can be done but inform the site admin.

This is the *reason* why *insert your service here* tags are being removed, with extreme prejuge and exchanged with the clients tags which are more relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But then, how do we add tags about services that also has a client application (like Last.FM)? Well, the solution is simple, just create a [last.fm-client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/last.fm-client) and explain exactly what should be asked with that tag. smplayer also has a youtube client, so what tag should be appropiated? Unless smplayer-youtube questions overwhelm smplayer normal question, I do not see the need of a new tag.